# Run app before login on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, mouse, osx-el-capitan

I'm using the [ShareMouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com) application to share my keyboard/mouse between my Windows and Mac Mini computer. It works great after logging in and having the app on startup. However, for the login screen I need to plug in my keyboard and mouse to the Mac mini which isn't ideal.

I'd like it for the app to start up before I login. I do not want to enable the auto-login feature for security reasons. Is it possible to run an app on the login screen on a Mac?

Comment: Yes, you need to turn it into a "launch daemon" (launchd).  Google around for "mac launchd", and then try the "Lingon" tool which makes this needlessly-complex setup a little easier.  There's a free version of Lingon which should work for you for this, and a more robust non-free version.  I have no affiliation with Lingon.

Comment: I gave Lingon a try but it did not run in the Login-Window as I wanted. I tried it with the user "root" as well as "all users". The application didn't even run even after logging in...(I did buy the license for Lingon). Screenshots: 
[http://i.imgur.com/MD4W0ob.png](http://i.imgur.com/MD4W0ob.png)
[http://i.imgur.com/hXfrhsG.png](http://i.imgur.com/hXfrhsG.png)

Answer (score 0):

When no one is logged in, the login prompt is running under user `root`. If you change the launch control for root, you should be able to get your app to run before login. As long as you're a local administrator, you can run `sudo su` to get root access from the command line.

Creating `launchctl` items is well documented on many sites so I won't repeat that here, but here a full description on the [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html).

Comment: I've also tried what jimtut mentioned in the comments above which also creates this launchd plist file. However that did not work. Not sure if this method works for OS X El-Capitan version.

Comment: Is your launch config calling a command line executable? GUI-based apps will likely not work in this scenario. You'll need to find if the app supports your use case and what the name of the file is that will work in this scenario. The vendor *should* be able to answer this.